# Add text view to dialog

Tags: android-layout, android

I'm trying to align right text in my dialog.
How can I do that ?
I've tried to:

```
TextView loadMsg = new TextView(context);
loadMsg.setText("טוען...");
loadMsg.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);       
dialog.setView(loadMsg);
dialog.show();
```

But the text does not show.

Comment: can you paste your complete code

Comment: that is the complete code to create the dialog

Comment: where you are intializing the dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you set the gravity **inside** the TextView. But if your TextView is laid out with `WRAP_CONTENT` the gravity really doesn't matter for such a short String. You should insert the `TextView` inside some `Layout`, specify `FILL_PARENT` and setting the layout as the Dialog content view

```
// width is FILL_PARENT -1, height is WRAP_CONTENT -2
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(-1, -2);
LinerLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context, params);
layout.addView(loadMsg, params);
dialog.setView(layout);
```

Alternatively, you can set the gravity on the layout itself and set the `TextView`'s width to `WRAP_CONTENT`

Answer (score 4):

Sub-way: Create a sub layout and set content view by this
`dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);`

And design the sub layout the way you like :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing LayoutParams in which you have to define heigh and width. If you use wrap_content for width then it would not be aligned as there will no be any extra space.